For loop in dataframe column
I want to iterate through dataframe column, ['Status'], and based on value calculate days since date in column ['Date'] and write to a third column,['Days'].
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
data={'Status':['Sold', 'Active', 'Sold', 'Active'],
      'Date': ['2024-10-02', '2024-05-06', '2024-11-01', '2024-07-12' ], 
      }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

d=date.today()
d=pd.to_datetime(d)
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])



for i in df['Status']:
    if i=='Active':
        values=df['Date']-d
    else:
        values=0


df['Days']=values
print(df)

Expected output:
Status       Date      Days
0    Sold 2024-10-02  0 days
1  Active 2024-05-06 -204 days
2    Sold 2024-11-01  0 days
3  Active 2024-07-12 -137 days

But the calculation is passed for all four rows:
Status       Date      Days
0    Sold 2024-10-02  -55 days
1  Active 2024-05-06 -204 days
2    Sold 2024-11-01  -25 days
3  Active 2024-07-12 -137 days


Can you explicit how you compute -204? Should it be -149?

Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First,  it groups by consecutive Status values using df['Status'].eq('Sold').cumsum() (cumsum). This expression creates a cumulative sum that increments each time Status equals Sold, segmenting df into groups of consecutive Status entries.

Within each group, the Date column is transformed via a lambda function that is applied to calculate the difference in days between the last and today dates of each group.

Finally, the resulting series of day differences is assigned to a new column Days in df.


df.assign(Days = df.groupby(df['Status'].eq('Sold').cumsum())['Date']
          .transform(lambda x: [0, (x.iloc[-1] - pd.Timestamp.today()).days]))

Output:
   Status       Date  Days
0    Sold 2024-10-02     0
1  Active 2024-05-06  -205
2    Sold 2024-11-01     0
3  Active 2024-07-12  -138


I think you want to mask the Active values with where and subtract the date of today:
df['Days'] = df['Date'].sub(d).where(df['Status'] == 'Active', pd.Timedelta(0))

Output:
   Status       Date      Days
0    Sold 2024-10-02    0 days
1  Active 2024-05-06 -204 days
2    Sold 2024-11-01    0 days
3  Active 2024-07-12 -137 days

And your loop (which you shouldn't use!) should have looked like:
ref = 0
df['Days'] = pd.Timedelta(0)
for i in df.index:
    if df.loc[i, 'Status'] == 'Active':
        df.loc[i, 'Days'] = df.loc[i, 'Date'] - d

In your current loop, you overwrite values at each step and since the output is a vector/Series, then only the last cycle is used in which values=df['Date']-d. This is the same as if you had run df['Days'] = df['Date']-d.

The question is a bit poorly phrased, but looks like OP wants something like: (df['Date'] - d).where(df['Status'] == 'Active', pd.Timedelta(0)). At least, that will get one the supposed expected output.

Thank you! do you mind answering why I shouldn't use for-loop to iterate through dataframe column? (I'm trying to learn python)

@ouroboros1 you're right, I had missed the definition of d. Thanks!

@slabbe because pandas is designed to vectorize operations. A loop is still happening but at a lower level (it's not explicit) and the data is stored in a more efficient format. In short two advantages: more compact code and more efficient code.

Other solutions are great, I tried to modify your loop just.
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date


data = {
    'Status': ['Sold', 'Active', 'Sold', 'Active'],
    'Date': ['2024-10-02', '2024-05-06', '2024-11-01', '2024-07-12'],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)


d = date.today()
d = pd.to_datetime(d)


df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Days'] = 0

# Loop through each row and calculate 'Days' based on 'Status'
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Status'] == 'Active':
        # Calculate the difference between 'Date' and today's date
        days_diff = (row['Date'] - d).days
        df.at[idx, 'Days'] = f"{days_diff} days"
    else:
        # For 'Sold' rows, set 'Days' to 0 with ' days' suffix
        df.at[idx, 'Days'] = "0 days"


print(df)

Output :
   Status       Date       Days
0    Sold 2024-10-02     0 days
1  Active 2024-05-06  -204 days
2    Sold 2024-11-01     0 days
3  Active 2024-07-12  -137 days

